# How to filter a StAX XMLStreamReader

Tags: java, sax, stax

I need to hook into an API that receives a StAX `XMLStreamReader` as the input, and filter the supplied stream (change the value of a certain attribute from true to false).

Looked at `StreamReaderDelegate`, but with that one I'd have to do a lot of coding to keep track of all access paths to the attribute in question.

Is there a better way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With StAX, you could use the event API instead and utilize the [EventReaderDelegate](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/util/EventReaderDelegate.html). The amount of code would be roughly the same though. Using delegates is also the recommended solution, so I'm afraid, there is no significantly better way.

Comment: Yeah. Gave up and coded a solution based on `StreamReaderDelegate`. Wasn't as bad as I thought.